# User and Password, Glassfish Admin Console

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

When you run the option to view domain management console from netbeans, it prompts me the username and password. What I've done is, downloaded glassfish4 zip format,unzipped and placed in a folder. Then I have added to Netbeans to run my applications. This worked without problem. In glassfish management console, admin username and password is set as "user: admin" and password as "adminadmin". However seeing Server properties in Netbeans, it has no Board Index or key. Accessing admin console from netbeans didn't prompt me username and password. Why ?

[Ventana de login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw4MO.png)

[Ventana de propiedades de glassfish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrbW7.png)

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, Netbeans never reveal glassfish password in properties window rather it points to glassfish installed location to access its properties.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, Netbeans never reveal glassfish password in properties window, rather it has its own file with username and password to access admin console. 
For example

```
.netbeans/dev/config/GlassFishEE6/Instances/.nbattrs

<attributes version="1.0">
    <fileobject name="instance">
        ...
        <attr name="username" stringvalue="admin"/>
        <attr name="password" stringvalue="adminadmin"/>
    </fileobject>
</attributes>
```